# 'Click' Function Not Working With List

Tags: jquery

I have an HTML list where the heading is "Please choose your city" and a list hidden of cities hidden. Once you click heading the list shows and you can click one and then they all disappear and you can only see the city. When I try to click the city again so I can choose a different city they don't open back up.

```
$=jQuery
$('.heading').click(function () {
    $('.city').show();
});

$('.city').click(function () {
    $(this).show();
    $('.heading').hide();
    $('.city').removeClass('cityhover');
    $(this).removeClass('city');
    $(this).addClass('cityhover');
    $('.city').hide();
});

$('.cityhover').click(function () {
    $('.heading').show();
    $('.city').show();
    $('.cityhover').removeClass('cityhover');
});
```

Comment: Please spend the time to indent your code properly. Nobody wants to read that.

Comment: make a jsfiddle?  Also are you sure your entire script is running?  It may be throwing an error at the lack of semicolon on the first line.  Check in console.

Comment: I do. Some people read 50 shades of gray as their secret bed time passion. I read unindented jQuery. Don't judge.

Comment: What's the markup look like?

Comment: Sorry I am new to jQuery I am not even sure what proper code looks like.... I can make a jsfiddle hold on. But no console is good.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aLj3V/

Here is the JSfiddle

Answer (score 1):

Here's why it's not working. Follow my comments.

```
$('.heading').click(function () {
    $('.city').show(); // ok we show all the cities
});


$('.city').click(function () { // clicked on a city
    $(this).show();
    $('.heading').hide();  // hide the heading
    $('.city').removeClass('cityhover'); // HERE you remove the cityhover class
    $(this).removeClass('city');
    $(this).addClass('cityhover');
    $('.city').hide();
});

$('.cityhover').click(function () { // but the only way to show the heading again is if you click one
    $('.heading').show();
    $('.city').show();
    $('.cityhover').removeClass('cityhover');
});
```

The trick is to use event delegation:

```
$('.citychooser').on('click', '.city', function () ....
```

http://jsfiddle.net/seancannon/rVq2T/

Answer (score 0):

jQuery does not reevaluate the selectors once they have run.
The `$('.cityhover').click(function () {` bit selects all elements that currently have the .cityhover element and attached a click handler, but does not make the className itself special.  Adding the class `cityhover` to and element later does not cause it to get the click handler.

My suggestion is to combine the click handlers for the .city and .cityhover classes and branch based on the current classname of the element clicked:

```
$('.city').click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('city')) {
        $(this).show();
        $('.heading').hide();
        $('.city').removeClass('cityhover');
        $(this).removeClass('city');
        $(this).addClass('cityhover');
        $('.city').hide();
    } else {
        $('.heading').show();
        $('.city').show();
        $('.cityhover').addClass('city').removeClass('cityhover');
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SS2v4/1)

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter of event delegation. You were binding events to elements, then changing the classes and expecting the events to update. You need to use event delegation in this case:

http://jsfiddle.net/u9wS3/

```
$(document).on('click', '.city', function () {
    $(this).show();
    $('.heading').hide();
    $('.city').removeClass('cityhover');
    $(this).removeClass('city');
    $(this).addClass('cityhover');
    $('.city').hide();
});

$(document).on('click','.cityhover', function () {
    $('.heading').show();
    $(this).addClass('city'); // also added this line
    $('.city').show();
    $('.cityhover').removeClass('cityhover');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote most of it, I prefer to set statuses and letting CSS handle the showing and hiding whenever appropriate.  As mentioned above, most of your issues come about because once you bind event handlers to a DOM object, it doesn't matter if you add or remove the class anymore, the things still stay bound.

Anycase, here's the code:
HTML unchanged

Javascript:

```
$ = jQuery;
$('.citychooser').on('click', '.heading', null,

function () {
    $(this).parent().addClass('choosing');
});

$('.citychooser').on('click', '.city', null,

function () {
    if($(this).closest('.citychooser').hasClass('choosing'))
    {
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(this).parent().removeClass('choosing').addClass('chosen');
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('choosing').removeClass('chosen');
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
.citychooser.chosen .heading{
    display:none;
}
.citychooser.chosen .city{
    display:none;
}
.citychooser.chosen .city.active{
    display:block;
}
.citychooser .city {
    display:none;
}
.citychooser.choosing .city {
    display:block;
}
.citychooser.choosing .header{
display:block;
}
.city:hover {
    background-color: #808080;
}
.cityhover {
    background-color: #808080!important;
}
.citychooser {
    width: 555px;
    float: right;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
.citychooser li {
    background-color: #cccccc;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
}
.citychooser .heading {
    text-indent: 20px;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aLj3V/7/

If you would rather the background stay dark while rechoosing until a new item in chosen, you can use the following javascript:

```
$ = jQuery;
$('.citychooser').on('click', '.heading', null,

function () {
    $(this).parent().addClass('choosing');
});

$('.citychooser').on('click', '.city', null,

function () {
    if($(this).closest('.citychooser').hasClass('choosing'))
    {
        $(this).parent().find('.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(this).parent().removeClass('choosing').addClass('chosen');
    } else {
        $(this).parent().addClass('choosing').removeClass('chosen');
    }
});
```

jsfiddle for that:http://jsfiddle.net/aLj3V/8/